# Cancelling setInterval from different places (NodeJS variable scope)

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm setting up a global variable and then storing a setInterval in it using a function that can be called from elsewhere in the module. I have also set up a function to cancel the setInterval that can be used to cancel the setInterval from other functions within the module. Please see snippet below:

```
var availabilityCheckInterval

function repeatAvailabilityCheckStart (session) {
  availabilityCheckInterval = setInterval(() => {
    // Call an API
    if (successful) {
      repeatAvailabilityCheckStop()
    }
  }, 15000)
}

function repeatAvailabilityCheckStop () {
  clearInterval(availabilityCheckInterval)
}
```

This is working on my local machine and staging environment, but seems to fail on production with concurrent users (or maybe it never actually worked...).

Am I missing something related to variable scope here? I am being naive using `setInterval()` in a production environment with concurrent users?

Comment: Why don't you have the `repeatAvailabilityCheckStart` return the integer handle to *the caller*, and let them cancel it? Why the variable that doesn't do anything? You could even, since these operations involve the *state* of the interval, wrap these in an class with a per request instance. $20 says that your production fail is coming from that 'global' (top level vars aren't actually global in Node.js).

Comment: The variable idea was to store the interval in a variable with global scope so it could be cancelled in multiple different places. I haven't thought of actually returning the interval handle to the caller. When you say wrap them in an object, do something like:

var whatever = {
  startInterval: () => {
    setInterval(() => {}, 2000)
  }
}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I said 'wrap it in an object' in the comments I meant something like this:

```
class Interval {
  constructor (f, n) {
    this.fn = f;
    this.repeatInterval = n;
    this.handle = null;
  }

  get running () {
    return this.handle !== null;
  }

  run (...args) {
    if (!this.running) {
      this.handle = setInterval(this.fn, this.repeatInterval, ...args);
    } else {
      // optionally throw, display msg, whatever
    }
    return this;
  }

  stop () {
    clearInterval(this.handle);
    this.handle = null;
    return this;
  }
}
```

now you can have a per request handle/interval. On each request just do

```
let intvl = new Interval(someFn, 15000).run();
```

and to clean up:

```
intvl.stop();
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, Jared. I had no idea you could approach a setInterval from an OOP point-of-view.

Comment: @tombraider no problem. I'm generally not much of an OOP kind of person but it does make a lot of sense in this case: you have a state (whether the interval is running) and some operations to manipulate it.